# Can I change the filter options in the video lens?  

Tags: unity, 12.04, unity-dash, lenses

Can I change the video options on the new dash menu?

To be more precise, on the  video file find menu filters, can I Add, Remove or Change what URLs can be include? If so how can I do?

For example if I want to change in the filters youtube shows to YouTube comedy, how you do it?

(I just installed MyUnity but from what I read and tested it won't fully work on Unity 2D, however I can change video filters using that)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the video lens doesn't allow an easy way to modify the filters it uses. If you want to modify them, my best guess would be to obtain the source for the lens and changing the filter settings by hand.

If you want some help in doing that, feel free to drop a comment below this answer and I will be happy to guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Manish, You can file a bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/candiru, it's the server providing the filter options.

You can also create a new scope for the lens, that will add a new option in Sources.